# Flask Gunicorn 80 port setup

Tags: nginx, flask, port, gunicorn

How to properly setup Gunicorn and Nginx - Flask with 80 port?
So I started from "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi". My application running in the address www.yyy.com/8000.

After I edited my config file /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  yoursite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;


}
}
```

But if I try to open www.yyy.com I see the default page "Welcome to nginx on the Amazon Linux AMI!" and after texting www.yyy.com:8000 I can access to my site! How to properly setup Nginx for access to 80 port? 
What I'm doing wrong, any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: try this :
`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://www.yyy.com;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/postdata.log postdata;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}`

Comment: Doesn't work, I had error because of include proxy_params, and access_log, I removed it but still the same!

Comment: what error shows on the console?

Comment: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf:6

Comment: where are you nginx setup? it's because is not on "/etc/nginx/proxy_params"

Comment: try with:

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

Comment: in this folder !/etc/nginx

Comment: try with the params i wrotte

Comment: Can we move to chat ?

Comment: I tried with proxy params, the same result ! What else I can Try ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you restarting nginx after making your changes?
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Have you verified that gunicorn is listening and handling your requests? From your host you can ensure its working by running
`curl http://localhost:8000`

Finally you may benefit from a more step by step guided approach. [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide provides a nginx/gunicorn/flask setup.